# What are the differences between Tensorflow's methods for exporting computational graph?

Tags: tensorflow

I understand one might want to have an overloaded method for coarser or finer grained control, but why to have them all named in a different way, scattered around the API? I am afraid I might be missing some differences between them.

So far I have found `tf.io.write_graph`,`tf.train.Saver.export_meta_graph` and `tf.train.export_meta_graph` (increasing number of parameters, not listing aliases). Can someone explain to me what is the rationale for having them all and when one is preferred over the other? Is any of them legacy? If so, it is not clearly marked in the documentation.